# jQuery code to return a string to another file

Tags: jquery

I have 2 jQuery files(`templates.js` & `page.js`). What I need is to access the templates(string or an array) that I have written in `templates.js` file to `page.js`. I have googled a lot & was not able to fix my issue. I'm loading `page.js` after `templates.js`.

Here is what I tried yet.

**templates.js**

```
var templates = function ($) {

    var templateheader = function() { 
        console.log('templateheader: Till this console is working.');
        return '<h1>Put your Header here</h1>';
    }

    var templatefooter = function() { 
        console.log('templatefooter: Till this console is working.');
        var templateCode = [];
        templateCode.push(['title', 'My title'], ['content', 'My content']); 
        return templateCode;
    }
    return {
        templateheader : function () {
            templateheader();
        },
        templatefooter : function () {
            templatefooter();
        }
    }
}(jQuery);
```

**page.js**

```
var page = function ($) {
    var accessTemplate = function() { 
        mytemplate = templates.templateheader();
        mytemplateArr = templates.templatefooter();
    }
    return {
        accessTemplate : function () {
            accessTemplate();
        }
    }
}(jQuery);
```

`console.log()` is working in both but on return, `undefined` is showing in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions aren't returning anything:

```
return {
    templateheader : function () {
        templateheader();
    },
    templatefooter : function () {
        templatefooter();
    }
}
```

I suspect you intended to return the values:

```
return {
    templateheader : function () {
        return templateheader();
    },
    templatefooter : function () {
        return templatefooter();
    }
}
```

Though honestly you could just simplify to:

```
return {
    templateheader : templateheader,
    templatefooter : templatefooter
}
```

or even:

```
return { templateheader, templatefooter }
```